# Get Month Name from a digit in Access Database?

Tags: function, ms-access, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to get month name from a month digit in access database.

I found this: `Format(Date, "mmmm")`, unfortunately i don't have the date, all i have are the months numbers so that function won't work.

is there an alternative i could use?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **MonthName(Month)** function available in MS-Access.

```
MonthName(3)            would return 'March'
MonthName(3, TRUE)      would return 'Mar'
MonthName(7, FALSE)     would return 'July'
```

---

In Access, the MonthName function returns a string representing the month given a number from 1 to 12.

The syntax for the MonthName function is:

```
MonthName ( number, [abbreviate] )
```

number is a value from 1 to 12, representing the month.

abbreviate is optional.  This parameter accepts a boolean value, either TRUE or FALSE. If this parameter is set to TRUE, it means that the month name is abbreviated. If this parameter is set to FALSE, the month name is not abbreviated.

Hope! this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Access has the `MonthName` function which gets the month number and returns the name of the month:

`MonthName(11)` will return `November`.

Answer (score 2):

Sales Month: `Format(DatePart("m",[invoice date]),"mmmm")`

does this help, it extracts the full month name from an Invoice Date