# Convert date to month name in sql Access Database

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2010, date-conversion

I am struggling to convert my  date (quote_date)  to name of the month in my query in access database. I managed to convert it to the month number but would rather present my results with name of the month instead. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
SELECT Month([quote_date]) as Month,
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Quote Motor Breakdown],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=1 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Motor Breakdown],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=2,1,0)) AS [Quote Travel Single],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=2 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Travel Single],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=3,1,0)) AS [Quote Travel Annual],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=3 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Travel Annual],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=4,1,0)) AS [Quoted Funeral Plan],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=4 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Funeral Plan],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=5,1,0)) AS [Quoted Car Insurance],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=5 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Car Insurance],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=6,1,0)) AS [Quoted Energy],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=6 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Energy],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=7,1,0)) AS [Quoted Home],
       Sum(IIf(reference.policy_ID=7 And status_ID=1,1,0)) AS [Sold Home],
       [Sold Motor Breakdown]
          + [Sold Travel Single]
          + [Sold Travel Annual]
          + [Sold Funeral Plan]
          + [Sold Car Insurance]
          + [Sold Energy]
          + [Sold Home] AS [Total Sold] 
  FROM reference
 WHERE (((reference.location_id)=2))
 GROUP BY Month([quote_date]);
```

Comment: Look at the *MonthName Function* topic in Access' help system.  You can give that function your month number and ask it to return the full or abbreviated month name.

Comment: I think month name function returns month name based on month indicated by number not actual date@HansUp

Comment: Yes, but you said you have the month number already, so why is that a problem?  Alternatively, you could use `Month([your date])` and feed that to `MonthName()` like this: `MonthName(Month([your date]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Month Name from a digit in Access Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066567/get-month-name-from-a-digit-in-access-database)

Comment: @HansUp MonthName(Month([your date])) resolved this isse. Thank you

Comment: @HansUp I have one more question - any idea how to make my months names to appear in the correct order: like jan, feb, mar etc. at the moment they seem to be randomly put in my first column

Comment: Are you sure they're not sorted alphabetically (starting with apr)?  Regardless, I think you need a column for the month number and then sort by that.  That means the additional column must also be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: for some reason moths are presented in random order..starting with December, but adding additional column resolved my issue . Again that you so much for your quick and helpful response @HansUp

Comment: You're welcome.  I was typing this as you submitted your last comment: `SELECT Month([quote_date]) As Month_number, MonthName(Month([quote_date])) As Month_name`  and later `GROUP BY Month([quote_date]), MonthName(Month([quote_date])) ORDER BY Month([quote_date])`  You may get away without the `ORDER BY` but I include it anyway.

Comment: @HansUp I don't think the `Month_number` must be explicitly present to order by it. It's already implicitly present as `MonthName(Month([quote_date]))`. You could even `order by quote_date` without an extra column. Columns need not be visible to be used as a sort criterion.

Comment: @PerlDog With Access 2010, you could exclude `Month([quote_date])` from the `SELECT` list, but then it must be present in the `GROUP BY` clause if you want to `ORDER BY Month([quote_date])`.  At least that is what my test shows me.  Do you see something else with the same or different version of Access?

Comment: @HansUp Umm, sorry, I'm coming from MySQL & DB2 and there you can order by virtually anything even if you don't mention it in the SELECT list, i.e. `select a,b from t order by c` would work. I didn't know Access differs in that.